# Getting a subset of HTML table columns to divide remaining width evently

Tags: html, html-table

Is it possible, with an HTML table, to specify a width for the first column, and then tell the remaining columns to divide the rest of the width evenly?

So for example, say I've got an HTML table with 5 columns.  I'd like to specify that the first column consumes 80% of the table's width.  Then, the next four columns consume the remaining 20% of the width, but those four columns **must** be evenly spaced among themselves regardless of their content.  That is, each of those four columns must consume exactly 5% of the total width.  I know for any one case I could just specify all those widths manually, but I'm looking for a dynamic solution where I just specify the first column and rest works itself out, regardless of the number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
table td:first-child { width:80%; }
```

Comment: That's awesome!  Thank you, I've been wondering for months how to do that!